# Nothing of Bootstrap5.2 works on phone

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Bootstrap works fine on pc. Even on mobile-view on the pc. But viewing the page on a phone itself isn't working. None of it, from the bootstrap navbar to the bootstrap buttons. Nothing works

Here's the view on pc

[image: image1]

And here's the view on phone

[image: image2]

Comment: How you load your CSS? Connect phone to PC, check dev tools if CSS is loaded

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading the Bootstrap files from localhost?  This will work on the PC assuming it's running the server.  If you try to load the page from a different device that isn't serving the files, it won't find them.